# C# -ExecuteNonQuery is an open and secure Connection setup. Current state of the connection: closed

Tags: c#

am new to C#. Please assist!

I keep having the following error: "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed." I am not able to insert into my database as well.

Below is my code:

```
string cinsiyet = "";
bool kayitkontrol = false;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xuAfen;Initial Catalog=PersonelTakip;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM personeller", connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    SqlCommand selectsorgu = new SqlCommand("select * FROM Personeller where tcno" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "'", baglanti);
                    
                    selectsorgu.ExecuteNonQuery(); **i am getting error here**
                    selectsorgu.Parameters.Clear();
                        baglanti.Close();

                    kayitkontrol = true;
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Lots of issues: you don't set the command's `.Connection`, you're not using parameters, you're using `ExecuteNonQuery` on a query that gives results, you're using MARS to substitute for what should probably be a query with a `JOIN` instead of client-side loops. Look into things like Dapper to make your life easier (and safer).

Comment: What is `baglanti`? Please provide a [mre], this code is impossible to debug.

Comment: @DavidG `baglanti` is Turkish for `connection`. Question is is it the same object (mistranslation) or is it a different one which has not been opened.

Comment: `if (reader != null)` is entirely unnecessary. What are you trying to achieve with the second `SELECT` command anyway?

Comment: `baglanti` is closed in the first iteration of the while loop, but you attempt to use it again in the next iteration. Perhaps you shouldn't be closing it until you've finished with, may be outside the loop!

Answer (score 2):

I think This loop is your issue:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    SqlCommand selectsorgu = new SqlCommand("select * FROM Personeller where tcno" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "'", baglanti);
    
    selectsorgu.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Will fail on the second iteration though the loop
    selectsorgu.Parameters.Clear();

    baglanti.Close(); // because the connection is closed here inside the loop

    kayitkontrol = true;
    break;
}
```

First time through it may or may not work depending on how `baglanti` is created and initialised.

The second time through has no chance of working though because the connection is closed in the first iteration! `baglanti.Close();` will make sure the connection is closed and cause it to fail the next time an attempt to use it is made.